# UITableView Cell visibleCells array goes wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a `UITableView` In a ViewController.
when `viewdidload`, I registered the cell by

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"tableViewCell"];
```

And here is the code in `UITableview` **delegate** and **datasource**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 25;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 100;
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"visible cell: %d",[[self.tableView visibleCells] count]);
static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"tableViewCell";

UITableViewCell* cell = cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    NSLog(@"nil -> create new");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"not nil reuse cell success");
}
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];

return cell;

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"will display: %d",indexPath.row);
}
```

And here is the result, when i scroll down the tableview, the log display cell for those cells is shown. but when i scroll to the bottom and scroll to the top. the log in willDisplayCell not shown. 
And the number of visible cells keep grow to 25. so the tableview seems think that all the 25 cells still visible. but on the screen just 5-6 cells will be display at a time.

I guess it may be a problem about static cell and dynamic cell? and i think i am using the dynamic one. cause the cell get from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is always not nil.

here is the output

```
2014-04-18 10:51:22.101 [5834:60b] visible cell: 6
2014-04-18 10:51:22.103 [5834:60b] not nil reuse cell success
2014-04-18 10:51:22.104 [5834:60b] will display: 6
2014-04-18 10:51:22.401 [5834:60b] visible cell: 7
2014-04-18 10:51:22.403 [5834:60b] not nil reuse cell success
2014-04-18 10:51:22.405 [5834:60b] will display: 7
2014-04-18 10:51:22.767 [5834:60b] visible cell: 8
2014-04-18 10:51:22.769 [5834:60b] not nil reuse cell success
2014-04-18 10:51:22.771 [5834:60b] will display: 8
2014-04-18 10:51:23.451 [5834:60b] visible cell: 9
2014-04-18 10:51:23.453 [5834:60b] not nil reuse cell success
2014-04-18 10:51:23.455 [5834:60b] will display: 9
2014-04-18 10:51:23.551 [5834:60b] visible cell: 10
2014-04-18 10:51:23.552 [5834:60b] not nil reuse cell success
2014-04-18 10:51:23.554 [5834:60b] will display: 10
2014-04-18 10:51:23.768 [5834:60b] visible cell: 11
2014-04-18 10:51:23.769 [5834:60b] not nil reuse cell success
2014-04-18 10:51:23.772 [5834:60b] will display: 11
2014-04-18 10:51:24.067 [5834:60b] visible cell: 12
2014-04-18 10:51:24.069 [5834:60b] not nil reuse cell success
```

Comment: I copied your code and "visible cell" was never more than 5. So you may need to post more code.

Comment: Since you have registered a class with a reuse identifier, the cell from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will always not be nil. Then  the log in willDisplayCell not shown while scrolling from bottom to top, it is because the cell at particular indexPath is already displayed when you scroll down. Then the number of visiblecells that keep growing, it is just right. If you want to know, the exact number of visible cells, you may try logging that number after [self.tableView reloadData].

Comment: @Siu Chung Chan check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows`

ex.:

```
NSArray indexArray = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure it out. It is pretty wried. The structure of my project is as follow.
I have a UITableView in the storyboard's FirstViewController
for the FirstViewController. when a cell is clicked. it pushs to the SecondViewController which contain a uitableview too.
and this uitableview is the tableview that i am asking above. 
Finally i fixed it by removing the storyboard and create the FirstViewController.Then everything just goes fine.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: dequeueReusableCell can be pretty quirky and I'm not sure I always understand the difference between `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

Comment: Not sure what removing the storyboard and re-creating FirstViewController would do to fix it. Using indexPathsForVisibleRows gave me valid data when visibleCells did not. But I only have this problem for a certain view controller, so I'm not sure what the difference is.